# Angular 6. Html Webpack Pluggin issue

Tags: angular, npm, command-line-interface, angular6

project was migrated from angular 5 to angular 6 version.
Thus, i have not such files as webpack.config.
Now it works under CLI engage.

After migration there is html webpack error:

[image]

The index.html actually placed at D:\Projects\DP...\src\index.html.

**Q:** How can i change 'root' for index.html using cli ???
I would like webpack look for index.html in D:\Projects\DP...\src\index.html by default.

Comment: Please add the output as text within your question, rather than using a picture (which is unreadable on my display).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that the CLI has the wrong path for your index.html file. The CLI configuration is in your Angular.json file. There is a field that take the path to your index.html in build options: 
You should have something like that :

"build": {

```
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/saturn-app",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
```

Hope this helped you!